# Angular touched/changed status of a form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I need to make my form to be `touched: false` `dirty: false` after I save its values and assign in proper places new IDs.

The form has a multilevel structure and has approximate next structure:

```
FormGroup
-- FormControl
-- FormControl
-- FormArray
  -- FormGroup
...
```

I run my save recursively due to unstable shape of a form.

After I save one `FormGroup` from FormArray I make `group.markAsUntouched({ onlySelf: !hasChildren })` and `group.markAsPristine({ onlySelf: !hasChildren })`.

However, after that I get "changed" "dirty" FormArray of "pristine" "unchanged" FormGroups.

I've tried also make `.parent` unchanged and untouch but that led to "unchanged" "pristine" FormArray in "changed" "dirty" FormGroup (the parent).

I never know how deep I am and if I can mark parent as untouched and pristine, because I save only those FormGroups which are "dirty" and "changed". Also I check if a root FormGroup is changed and dirty before card close, so it's vital to keep a real values.

In docs it's said that `markAsUntouched` and `markAsPristine` recalculate corresponding values of AbstractControl's parent however it's not happening.

Answer (score -1):

you can specify current value in the reset method
https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#reset

Comment: I didn't say a word about form reset.

Comment: from the link I gave you: "Resets the FormGroup, marks all descendants are marked pristine and untouched, and the value of all descendants to null." but you can specify the value: this.form.reset(currentValueOfTheForm)

Answer (score -1):

Reset the form by calling reset method.

```
form.reset();
```